# Linear transformation as dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that to every $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^1)$ corresponds a unique $\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}$. Prove also that $\Vert A \rVert=|\mathbf{y}|$.

**Proof:** Let $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^1)$ and $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ then $\mathbf{x}=x_1e_1+\dots+x_ne_n$ where $\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}$ is the standard  basis. Since $Ae_j=\lambda_j\in \mathbb{R}^1$ for $j=\overline{1,n}$ then let's define $\mathbf{y}=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Hence $$A\mathbf{x}=A\sum_{j}x_je_j=\sum \limits_{j}x_jAe_j=\sum \limits_{j}x_j\lambda_j=\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}$$
Such vector $\mathbf{y}$ is unique since $A$ is linear mapping.

$$\lVert A\rVert=\sup \limits_{|\mathbf{x}|=1}|A\mathbf{x}|=\sup \limits_{|\mathbf{x}|=1}|\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}|\leqslant \sup \limits_{|\mathbf{x}|=1}|\mathbf{x}||\mathbf{y}|=|\mathbf{y}|.$$ The above inequality is the result of Scwarz inequality. Thus $\lVert A\rVert \leqslant |\mathbf{y}|.$

But taking $\mathbf{x}=\left(\frac{y_1}{\sqrt{y_1^2+\dots+y_n^2}},\dots,\frac{y_n}{\sqrt{y_1^2+\dots+y_n^2}}\right)$. We see that $|\mathbf{x}|=1$ and $|A\mathbf{x}|=|\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}|=|\mathbf{y}|$. Hence $\lVert A\rVert=|\mathbf{y}|$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: As it appears you're just being asked to prove the Riesz representation theorem, [this pdf](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-103-fourier-analysis-theory-and-applications-spring-2004/lecture-notes/lec_13.pdf) (or any proof of the riesz representation theorem) may be useful for you.

Comment: @Mark, I am not familiar with element of Hilbert space theory and your link is little bit hard to me. I need in proof for my problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Can anyone look at my solution above? I'll edit it soon.

Comment: Small things: it's *the* standard basis.  You might want to make it a bit more clear what $\lambda_j$ is - it seems like it's the $j$th component of $A$ from your definition, but your definition of $A$ is a little awkward (you defined it as a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ - those have a specific name.  "Linear functionals".  If you haven't learned it, don't worry about it though).  The rest seems fine.

Comment: @Mark, I edited some moments of my proof and added solution. What do you think about it?

Comment: Yeah, it seems fine.  I'd do some things slightly differently (when you show that $||A||=|y|$, I would find it more natural to define $x=\frac{y}{||y||}$, which is known as $y$ being "normalized").  Having more of an explanation why $A$ being a linear mapping implies the $y$ in $Ax=x\cdot y$ is unique might be a good idea - currently you're making a statement without explicitly defending it.  This can be fine if you've used that reasoning before in other proofs, but if you haven't it's a little sketchy.

Comment: This $y$ is unique since the components of $y$ are $Ae_j$ and $A$ is mapping (to every $e_j$ mapping $A$ corresponds unique $u_j$ such that $Ae_j=u_j$ -- it's definition of mapping). I explicitly show that $Ax=x\cdot y$. I can't understand your remark.

Comment: The proof is perfect. (To be very picky, at the last step you need to split into two cases $y = 0$ and $y\neq 0$ as your last $x$ is not well defined if $y=0$.

Comment: @JohnMa, Yes you are right! Case $y=0$ is also actual. Thank you for remark!